# Distributing a String over a tuple

Tags: python, string, list, recursion, tuples

So I am trying to distribute a String over a tuple.
For example:

```
x = ["a", ("b", ("c", "d"))]
```

Then after I would like to have

```
x = ["a", ("bc", "bd")]
```

And then finally:

```
x = ["abc", "abd"]
```

However the tuple does not always have to be the second element:
For example:

```
x = [(("c", "d"), "b"), "a"]
```

Would simplify to:

```
x = [("cb", "db"), "a"]
```

And finally:

```
x = ["cba", "dba"]
```

I am wondering how I would go about writing a single function to simplify the first expression directly to the last.

What i've tried so far is:

```
def distribute(x):
    if isinstance(x, list) and any([True if isinstance(o, tuple) else False for o in x]):
        if isinstance(x[0], tuple):
            return (x[0][0] + x[1], x[0][1] + x[1])
        else:
            return (x[0] + x[1][0], x[0] + x[1][1])

print (distribute(["a", ("b", "c")]))
```

Final Edit:
Editted Oscars code to work for my second example:

```
def dist(tpl):
    if not isinstance(tpl[1], tuple) and not isinstance(tpl[0], tuple):
        return tpl
    if isinstance(tpl[1], tuple):
        ret = dist(tpl[1])
        return [tpl[0] + ret[0], tpl[0] + ret[1]]
    elif isinstance(tpl[0], tuple):
        ret = dist(tpl[0])
        return [ret[0] + tpl[1], ret[1] + tpl[1]]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sounds like a job for recursion.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem on recursion

Comment: That's cool. What's your question?

Comment: Note: `True if isinstance(o, tuple) else False` is exactly equivalent to simply `isinstance(o, tuple)`. Also, +1 for improving your question in response to the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it's a recursive solution that works for both examples in the question, under the assumption that both elements in a tuple are never going to be tuples at the same time.

```
def dist(tpl):
    if not isinstance(tpl[0], tuple) and not isinstance(tpl[1], tuple):
        return tpl
    elif isinstance(tpl[0], tuple):
        ret = dist(tpl[0])
        return [ret[0] + tpl[1], ret[1] + tpl[1]]
    else:
        ret = dist(tpl[1])
        return [tpl[0] + ret[0], tpl[0] + ret[1]]
```

It works as expected:

```
dist(["a", ("b", ("c", "d"))])
=> ['abc', 'abd']

dist([(("c", "d"), "b"), "a"])
=> ['cba', 'dba']
```

Comment: Downvoter: my code now works for both examples (the second one was added later, after my first answer). Care to reconsider the down vote?

Comment: @hcwhsa I see. The second example was added after my first answer, I updated my answer to take it into consideration.

Comment: @user2954175 if this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking on the check mark to its left ;)